# Fluid hoverable Drop-down menu using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to make a fluid drop-down menu like the on in udemy(https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3GFF.png) but the options inside my drop-down doesn't appear. Is there is anything i'm doing wrong?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Heading 1 </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Opt 1</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Opt 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post the css you're working with as well. Unless you strictly need to use a <ul> consider using a more semantic html tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes with the use of the class="dropdown-menu" on the UL tag inside of the div.dropdown-menu. If you remove that class, you will see the content inside the dropdown.